# Coordinate Transformation across different media

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, coordinate-systems

I have an arrangement that is as follows :
(1) inner cylinder(radius r1) filled with water
(2) outer cylinder(concentric, radius r2>r1) made of glass

I have a sensor S1 at radius r(r1) at angle beta.

I want to do a coordinate transformation such that 
(a) the sensor S1 is the new origin.
(b) the whole system is made of glass, (ie an eqvt full glass version of the system)